# UICollectionViewのセルが表示されない。

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

UICollectionViewをソースコードのみ（Storyboard,Xibは使用しない）で実装していますが、セルが表示されません。
※UICollectionView自体は表示されていますが、「UICollectionViewDelegate」「UICollectionViewDataSource」が呼び出されてないようです。

UICollectionViewとセルのそれぞれに背景色を設定しましたが、UICollectionViewのみ反映されています。
また、各ソースコードにログ出力処理を追加しましたが、delegate,DataSourceは呼び出されていないようです。

### ヘッダーファイル（.h）

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

### 実装ファイル（.m）

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource> {
    UICollectionView *coll;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"===viewDidLoad===");
    coll.delegate = self;
    coll.dataSource = self;

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout* flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    coll = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
    coll.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor;
    [coll registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    [self.view addSubview:coll];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"===numberOfItemsInSection===");
    return 10;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"===cellForItemAtIndexPath===");
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
    return cell;
}

@end
```

背景色が赤色のセルが10個表示される事を期待します。

Comment: `UICollectionView`をインスタンス化する前に`delegate`と`dataSource`を設定している様に見えるので、作成したインスタンスに正しく`dataSource`も`delegate`も設定されず、結果として`dataSource`や`delegate`メソッドが呼び出されていないのではないでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます！！dataSourceやdelegateの位置をインスタンス化後に移動させると正常に動きました！！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dataSourceやdelegateの位置をインスタンス化後に移動させると正常に動きました！！

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource> {
    UICollectionView *coll;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"===viewDidLoad===");

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout* flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    coll = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
    coll.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor;
    [self.view addSubview:coll];

    [coll registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    coll.delegate = self;
    coll.dataSource = self;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"===numberOfItemsInSection===");
    return 10;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"===cellForItemAtIndexPath===");
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: 質問内容を修正してしまうと、後から読んだ人にとって質問内容が意味をなさなくなってしまいます。質問はそのままにしておいて、回答の方に修正したコードを記載するようにしてください。